# How to resolve outgoing random pings from my ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: networking, server

I got a server from Leapswitch India and ask them to install Ubuntu 20.04
The server was suspended claiming that the bandwidth was consumed.
After getting it up again by reinstalling server OS. I checked using iftop and found that the server is pinging to random websites.
Mostly on the LeapSwitch network.

How to understand what is the problem and which script is doing to so.
Leap Switch staff is not so helpful and ignoring the problem after informing them.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man tcpdump`, and run `tcpdump`, outputting to a file (NOT the terminal) to capture an overnight's worth of packets (hands off while capturing). Analyze the packet stream using `wireshark`.

Look for extra userids in `/etc/passwd`.

Look for strange `cron` jobs in `/etc/cron.*`.

To ask if a file is in a package `dpkg -S` followed by the full path to the file.